# Search Function in Firestore Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I'm trying to search for current chats in firestore by the user name but I get here all the chats I have even when I type a letter that is not included

```
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> chatsSearchService(
  String userId, String searchValue) {
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(userId)
    .collection('chats')
    .where('userName', isEqualTo: searchValue)
    .snapshots();
```

I want to only get the chat which contains the letters I type

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirestoreServices()
          .chatsSearchService('${cubit.userModel?.id}', cubit.searchValue),
      builder: (context,
          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snap) {
        if (!snap.hasData) {
          return Container();
        }
        
        return ListView.separated(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              LastMessagesModel currentChats =
                  LastMessagesModel.fromJson(snap.data?.docs[index].data());

              return InkWell(
                
                child: searchChatBody(user, context, currentChats),
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Divider();
            },
            itemCount: snap.data!.docs.length);
      }),
```

Comment: an example will help me what you want to achieve or maybe a screenshot of what you are currently getting.

Comment: I want when I type a letter for example "Y" in the textField (searchValue here is the value in onChanged) a list will be displayed with all the users who have "Y" in their name

Comment: in where clause use isGreaterThanOrEqualTo instead of isEqualTo. Then use startsWith() for example LastMessagesModel.fromJson(snap.data?.docs[index].data().startsWith(searchValue));

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?